# How to publish an app for testing

Tags: iphone, testing, deployment

I'm currently creating an iPhone app and we need some testing with about 20~30 users.

Actually we put the app on our iPhone by connecting the iPhone to the computer and debugging the app.

But now we need to have a more efficient way to install the app on iPhone but without submitting it to Apple Store and also without the need to connect the iPhone to the computer hosting Xcode.

Do you think there is a way to do that ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah there's a very slick way to do adhoc distribution under iOS 4 that's outlined [here](http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/). This method involves absolutely zero usb cables and does not require a jailbroken device either. Perfectly legit and above board.

Comment: Many thanks ! Didn't find this searching Apple's website, that fit all my needs :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AdHoc installation. Please see [this nice Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/xcode/conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html), it should cover every step necessary even with step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I use www.TestFlightApp.com, it's a great services, not out yet, but recently opened up their beta's, it does all the ad hoc stuff for you alls you need to do is invite testers, let it export it to your dev portal. Then you just upload the ipa to the site, and all your testers get an email.